# Does Hola (VPN service) upload data and how can I track it?

Tags: internet

Hola is a VPN service which claims to rely on peers to unblock websites and accelerate browsing. If it relies on peers, clearing there must be peer to peer uploading taking place. What is the easiest way to track how much data it uploads? Also, are there any guarantees besides its personal statement that it isn't uploading personal information?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of programs that should help you identify the traffic: [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), [Microsoft Message Analyzer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226) and [Sysinternals Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx).